# Is it possible with aiogram to know, who sent the message?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

So the Telegram Bot can do different actions, depending on who activated the command. This concerns aiogram, a framework for Telegram Bot API

Comment: Ok... can we see the code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple filtering system:

1. Create a dict/database with user_id's and their roles
2. Get the role from that dict/db by id and do the action

This solution in code:

```
roles={1234:'Admin', 1243:'User', 1223:'Moderator'}

@dp.message_handler()
async def handler(message: types.Message) -> None:
    role=roles[message.from_user.id]

    if role=='Admin': do_action()
    elif role=='User': do_another_action()
    elif role=='Moderator': do_yet_another_action()

#you can add a check at start, to see if person even has a role
#if message.from_user.id in roles:
```